# How to change the value of an element within a list using purrr (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

If I have the following list

```
list1 <- list(list(a = 2, b = 3), list(c = 4, d = 5))
list2 <- list(e = "a", f = "b")
mylist <- list(list1, list2)
```

What is the easiest way to change the value of `a` within `mylist` to a different value (preferably in `purrr`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
list1[[1]][[1]] <- newvalue
```

Comment: Hi @FrsLry , looking to achieve this but within ```purrr```, so that I can use pipe operators to change items in a list.

Comment: Honestly, it seems to be a mess to work with lists in R. Maybe you can find a (not so elegant) answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604391/modifying-specified-list-elements-r)

Comment: Thanks @FrsLry , I've noticed that its difficult to achieve the same effect using pipe operators so I'll go with your solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `pluck` :

```
purrr::pluck(mylist, 1, 1, 'a') <- 'new_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try `purrr::modify_in`.  This will return the `mylist` object with the updated `a` value.

```
purrr::modify_in(mylist, c(1, 1, "a"), "new_value")
```